# OpenCV has no drawKeypoints function

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Python 3.7.1 and OpenCV 4.0.0
I'm just testing FAST algorithm with various configurations, and I have problems with the `drawKeypoints` function. In fact, I copied OPenCV tutorial code, just to realize that the function needs a third argument, the output image. After that, everything was working, and I commited to the repo.
Later on, I had to format my pc, and reinstall everything. Now, whenever I try to run that code, it complains about `module 'cv2' has no attribute 'drawKeypoints'`. Here is the most basic code I had running after the format.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], 0)
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create()
kp = fast.detect(img,None)
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(255,0,0))
cv2.imshow('Original',img)
cv2.imshow('Detected',img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've been looking, and I have no clue about what could be wrong with this code.

Comment: maybe it is related to this bug: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13406 ?  it is solved in the git repository, but I do not know if it solved in the OpenCV python package

Comment: @api55 It seems so, but not solved in the opencv package. Last build for manjaro was 2018/11/21 so no. I'll look  for a way to compile it for python 3 and manjaro, as it is somewhat urgent.

Comment: @api55 Could you write that as an answer? Finally it was the problem. The manjaro repository for OpenCV was with that problem, but the pip one (not updated) didn't have that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks related to [this bug](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13406) which has a solution in the git repository (sources), but not necessarily is updated in the installation using pip. It was merged on Dec 11 2018, so for the time of this question it was probably not updated.

Maybe getting an updated wheel could solve the problem or you can build it yourself from sources. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) you can also see how this is generated (the one from pip install) and also offers you the tool to build your own opencv wheel.